# .htaccess Redirect Rule for & Character

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im not experienced with .htaccess files. I apologize for misconceptions in advance.

If have the following rule in my .htaccess file to accept requests without a filename extension:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^index/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([öäü0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) index.php?id=$1&term=$2 [NC,L]
```

An URL like **domain.com/index/2/jonathan** should be (internally) redirected to **domain.com/index.php?id=2&term=jonathan**. This works fine except for terms which include the **&** character.

Adding the **&** character to the rule like this didnt help:

`RewriteRule ^index/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([öäü0-9a-zA-Z_-&]+) index.php?id=$1&term=$2 [NC,L]`

How can I include the & character correctly inside the rule?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: You probably need the `B` flag here, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve the problem using the B flag:
`RewriteRule ^index/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([öäü&0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) index.php?id=$1&term=$2 [B,NC,L]`

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer (and later accept it). This helps other readers.

Comment: Note that your regex should be anchored, otherwise you are matching too much (and unnecessarily matching URLs _with_ a file extension, which forces an unnecessary filesystem check). eg. `/index/2/jonathan/anything` would also match and serve the same content, which potentially opens your site up to abuse and is bad for SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I was able to solve the problem using the B flag:

```html
RewriteRule ^index/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([öäü&0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) index.php?id=$1&term=$2 [B,NC,L]
```